# Only show last record in html

Tags: python, html, django

I am new for Django. I want to list all passenger in each flight. However, the display is only the passenger of last flight only.  I think it may be something wrong in my html.   My code in view.py as follows:-

```
def list  (request):
flights = Flight.objects.all()
for flight in flights: 
    for flight in flights: 
        passengers = Flight.objects.get(pk=flight.id).passengers.all()
        for passenger in passengers:
             context = {
            "flights": flights,
             "flight":flight,
            "passengers": passengers,
            "passenger":passenger,     }
```

My HTML is listed as follow:-

```
{% block body %}
<h1>Flights</h1> <div class = "list">
{% for flight in flights %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'flight' flight.id %}">
            Flight #{{ flight.id }}: {{ flight.origin }} to {{ flight.destination }}
        </a>
   <ul>
    <li>Flight Number: {{ flight.id }}</li>
    <li>Origin: {{ flight.origin }}</li>
    <li>Destination:  {{ flight.destination }}</li>
    <li>
        {% for passenger in passengers %}    <---  I think it should have some instruction to point to flight 
        Passengers:
        <ul>
        <li> {{passenger}} </li>
            {% empty %}
        <li>No passengers</li>
    {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</li>{% endfor %}</div>{% endblock %}
```

Last flight passenger appear only. 
Would any one can help me to review if any missing ?  Thanks a lot for your help 
[The results is only show last flight passenger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvEYJ.jpg)

Comment: move `{% for passenger in passengers %}` inside `<ul>` element

Comment: I put it under {% for flight in flights %}  - also no use !

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems within your view.

1. You loop twice of your flights, but this could be a paste issue?
2. Your solution is quite performance heavy, as for each flight two queries happen. Your flight is retrieved again with the `.get` and then you get the passengers. With 1 flight you do 3 queries, but with 100 flights you'll do 201 queries.
3. You overwrite your context.

```py
def list_passengers(request):
    flights = Flight.objects.all().prefetch_related('passengers')

    context = {
        "flights": flights
    }
```

So by adding a prefetch related every passenger is retrieve in one extra query. Which makes the amount of queries now always two.

Now we need to update the template to work with your new context.

```
{% block body %}
<h1>Flights</h1> 
<div class = "list">
{% for flight in flights %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'flight' flight.id %}">
            Flight #{{ flight.id }}: {{ flight.origin }} to {{ flight.destination }}
        </a>
   <ul>
    <li>Flight Number: {{ flight.id }}</li>
    <li>Origin: {{ flight.origin }}</li>
    <li>Destination:  {{ flight.destination }}</li>
    <li>
        Passengers:
        <ul>
        {% for passenger in flight.passengers.all %}     
            <li> {{passenger}} </li>
        {% empty %}
            <li>No passengers</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Blackeagele - it works thanks !  But I don't understandflights = Flight.objects.all().prefetch_related('passengers')   <--- is this 'passengers' point to HTML file.    flight.passengers.all -  I don't know I can use this variable.   When I edit in " Python shell" ,  flight.passenger  -  it will appear error.

Comment: `prefetch_related` is a method which retrieves all passengers depending on the flights in the queryset. For more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related. If you want to test it in django shell. Do `./manage.py shell`. And do 
```flights =  Flight.objects.all().prefetch_related('passengers')
print(flights[0].passengers.all())
``` Furthermore, `flight.passengers.all` is allowed in the template. Django understands this is a method and will do `.all`. And if its correct, could approve the answer :)